# nginx + uwsgi не слушает socket

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

Подключаю `nginx` и `uwsgi`. `nginx` возвращает 503 ошибку. В `errors.log`

```
2021/07/19 18:58:34 [error] 23198#23198: *13 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 104.131.22.119, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.2:8080/", host: "fixmessaging.com"
2021/07/19 19:01:54 [error] 23198#23198: *15 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 104.131.22.119, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.2:8080/", host: "fixmessaging.com"
```

Почему `nginx` берет за `upstream` **127.0.0.2:8080**, в `sites-enabled/avito_car_bot` лежит то что `uwsgi_pass` слушает `avito_car_bot.sock`

```
server {
    server_name avito_car_bot;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/avito-pokrishki/avito_car_bot/avito_car_bot.sock;
    }
}
```

В `avito_car_bot.ini` лежит:

```
[uwsgi]
module = web.wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5


socket = avito_car_bot.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

avito_car_bot.sock создается.

**Почему `nginx` берет из 8080, а не `avito_car_bot.sock`??**

Comment: Судя по логу запрос попал в другой server (либо вы зачем-то отредактировали лог). Вы точно перезапустили nginx?

Comment: @AlexeyTen я перезапустил nginx. Вот что лежит в директории sites-enabled: 000-default  avito_car_bot

Comment: @AlexeyTen может ли это быть из-за 000-default?

Comment: `sudo nginx -t` что пишет?

Comment: @andreymal пишет ok

Comment: Удалите `000-default`